# Touchpad Unity UI

Tags: unity, gui

For my Unity game, I want a touch surface (UI Panel).
I started implementing a MonoBehavious that should handle `touch-started`, `touch-ended`, `touch-moved/dragged` and `double-tap` with custom methods.

I read some forum posts and the scripting documentation, but I don't understand how have to do this.

Which base-class do I have to use? What methods should be implemented/ overridden?

Answer (score 1):

Unity's standard UI elements respond to both touch inputs and mouse inputs.

If you want to implement custom events that trigger on touch, use the Input class. For instance, [Input.touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) returns all the touches that are currently happening at that instant.

Comment: Thank you very much, however I found the answer here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/875535/event-trigger-component-how-to-access-input-data.html.

Comment: @000000000000000000000 To help others with the same question find the solution, it's worth posting a description as an answer on this question, and marking it accepted. That way, even if the answers.unity3d link breaks in the future, the information will still be accessible.